# how to return data through function when fetching data from firebase realtime-database in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

i am developing an android app with react native i wanted to return firebase data whenever i call this fetchUserData() it prints the fetched data within the function but i want to return fetched data through fetchUserData() function.

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import Fire from '../api/Fire'

// create a component
class HomeScreen extends Component {

state = { 
    coins : 0
}

componentDidMount(){
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user =>{ 
        Fire.fetchUserData(user).then(response =>{
        this.setState({
             coins : response.coins
         })
       }
    })
    console.log(this.state.coins) // prints undefined
};
```

Fire.js

```
fetchUserData(user){
    if(user){
        return firebase
            .database()
            .ref('users')
            .once("value", snapshot=>{
                if(snapshot.child(user.uid).exists()){
                    snapshot.child(user.uid).val() //how to return this data through fetchUserData()
                }
            })
    }
}
export default new Fire();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `return` inside the `once` callbvack`in`fetchUserData`:

```
fetchUserData(user){
    if(user){
        return firebase
            .database()
            .ref('users')
            .once("value", snapshot=>{
                if(snapshot.child(user.uid).exists()){
                    return snapshot.child(user.uid).val()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

---

The above code loads the entire `users` node to return the data for a single user, which is highly inefficient when you have multiple users. You can significantly improve its scalability by only loading the data for the one user you're interested in:

```
fetchUserData(user){
    if(user){
        return firebase
            .database()
            .ref('users')
            .child(user.uid)
            .once("value", snapshot=>{
                if(snapshot.exists()){
                    return snapshot.val()
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: it returns something like { _40: 1,
_65: 0,
_55: null,
 _72: 
 { onFulfilled: null,
onRejected: [Function],
promise: { _40: 0, _65: 0, _55: null, _72: null } } }

Comment: Looks like a promise, which is correct. But you're using `fetchUserData(user).then(response =>{` so in there the `response` should be the JSON you have for that user in the database (I can't say what that is).